# equivalent of httpwebrequest in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

In my controller, based on user post, i want to make a call to an external provider site to get process some data and get results.

example: say i want to invoke google map api at the following url

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/output?

This call returns an xml object with data, which I would like to use.

Only using google as an example here, but concept is the same.

How would I make the call in spring mvc controller or in the business[service] layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across jersey client which allows me to go against RESTful service.

This is the link I used:

[Jersey Sample Client](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restful-java-client-with-jersey-client/)

[Jersey Sample Client from oracle](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/consuming_restful_web_services_with)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can open a http request inside a controller /Service ( Service sounds better )

I remember doing in other web framewoks with Apache http client (http://hc.apache.org/ ) but I would try google-api-client or google-api-client-servlet .

I m trying right now .